# Complex integration problem involving exponetials

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Need help evaluating the following:

$$\int_0^{\frac{uy}{(1-u)}} x^{(k/2)-1} * e^{-(x+y/2)} \,dx$$

Preferably with a couple steps to help me understand where I am going wrong.

So if i integrate with respect to x, i get:

$$\ {\frac{2x}{k}}^{(k/2)} * e^{-(x+y/2)} * -2 |_0^{\frac{uy}{(1-u)}}=$$
add +1 to x's exponent, and divided x by k/2, and multiplied by the denominator of the natural number's exponent.

Then insert the variables in place of x and subtract top from bottom and get:

$$[{\frac{2{\frac{uy}{(1-u)}}}{k}}^{(k/2)} * e^{-(\frac{\frac{uy}{(1-u)}+y}2)} * -2] - 0$$

do some simplification and get:

$${\frac{-4{uy}}{k(1-u)}}^{(k/2)} * e^{-\frac{y}{2(1-u)}} $$

but the answer should be:

$$(\frac{uy}{(1-u)})^{(k/2)-1} e^{-(\frac{\frac{uy}{(1-u)}+y}2)} (\frac y{{(1-u)}^2}) \,$$

I am doing something horribly wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How can anyone help you to understand where you're going wrong if you didn't write anything at all of your *own* work?!

Comment: I've worked this problem several ways, but never get the correct answer. Added one of my solutions and what the answer should be, hope that helps

Comment: How come after you write "If I integrate with respect to $\;x\;$ I get:..." ...and then you write again an integral!? And even if that integral sign is only a typo, how did you get that expression?

Comment: Another thing: is it $\;e^{-x-\frac y2}\;$ or else $\;e^{-\frac{x+y}2}\;$ ?

Comment: The integral sign should be the "evaluate from 0 to (uy/1-u)" sign(fixed in original question), the expression i get comes from adding one to the exponent and dividing by the new exponent (x^(k/2) -1  -> x^(k/2)/(k/2)). I guess I'm a little confused on integrating the natural number exponent.

Comment: But you can differentiate the expression you wrote after "In I integrate..." and you do **not** get the original integrand. That expression is completely wrong, imo.